Are There Tools That Intelligently Separate Image Elements by Depth?
What software or platform, if any,  can automatically separate elements in an image or illustration into distinct layers based on their perceived depth?

Google's Gemini 2.0 LLM has a "Spatial Understanding" feature that is currently (Dec 2024) in Beta. You can check out a Sample App on Google AI Studio, watch a video by Google or read a blog post by another developer has used this feature.
Also there are  depth-estimation-models on HuggingFace but often these are research models which require in-depth domain knowledge and powerful hardware.

knb, Gemini 2.0's spatial understanding is impressive, but I am looking for a platform that can automatically separate image regions with the same depth into individual images.
